# Ubuntu is already installed but I want to install Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, windows-10

I'm new in Ubuntu, I want to install windows 10 on my Lenovo Thinkstation, Ubuntu 16.04 is already installed but I want to install windows 10. When I try for windows installation through USB, window can't find any hard drive for installation. 
How I can install windows? I don't need Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Use gparted to free up space for the W10 install....

Makeva ntfs partition about 60g should do ...

Shut down and reboot to the DVD drive ... install on the ntfs that it will want to ...when all done install .... set windows to reboot ::;;;;;

Strict cavet here .... set windows to reboot --- do not shut down ( it only makes problems when you shut down)

Hit and hold the power button to force a emergency shutdown ----OR

Y you could have prep beforehand with the live Ubuntu image on a flash drive ... if the bios was set to boot from USB as first device .....

reboot Windows and while it was cycling through the point where it looks like it just turned off the didn't you stick in the USB drive and a good chance it'll be off runnin on live Ubuntu image ....

Get booted into the live Ubuntu. connect to the internet install grub Magic or go the hard way and try to figure out how to redo the grub entries but grub magic works great for me, it scans everything reorganizes the grub partition setup and it will make it so that Ubuntu will be booted first and if you want to do something else your Windows installation will be in the last of the list.... easy peasy

Comment: Please provide a link to grub Magic or whatever it's called in the answer.

Comment: OP does not want to keep Ubuntu, OP wants to replace it with Windows.

Comment: Are you aware your keyboard seems to have both sticky and skipping keys?